# How to set NAs under the condition that another column contains a specified string?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with the following information:

```
test_01 <- data.frame(Party_1 = c("ABC", "ABC", "ABC"),
                      Party_2 = c("DEF", "DEF", "GHI"),
                      Party_3 = c("GHI", "Independent", "Independent"),
                      Ministry_No_P1 = c(12,10,10),
                      Ministry_No_P2 = c(6,5,2),
                      Ministry_No_P3 = c(2,1,1)
                      )
test_01
```

I am now looking for a way to set the number of ministries (`Ministry_No_Px`) of the respective `Party_x` on NA whenever in a `Party_x` column a string named "Independent" is found.

I want to link the setting of `Ministry_No_Px` to NA on the condition of finding an "Independent" string in `Party_x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the columns are corresponding order, create a logical matrix with the string columns i.e. column index from 1 to 3, and use that to assign the corresponding values in numeric column 4 to 6 as `NA`

```
test_01[4:6][test_01[1:3] == 'Independent'] <- NA
```

-output

```
test_01
#  Party_1 Party_2     Party_3 Ministry_No_P1 Ministry_No_P2 Ministry_No_P3
#1     ABC     DEF         GHI             12              6              2
#2     ABC     DEF Independent             10              5             NA
#3     ABC     GHI Independent             10              2             NA
```